# Uploading file via WebClient

Tags: c#, upload, webclient

I've got to upload a file (XML that's been generated with my previous code) to a web service that gave me following information:

URL (`http://www.example.com/upload`)
Port (1234)
Method (POST or PUT)

So I searched a lot over here and found some code using WebClient that seemed to do just what I needed.

```
try
{
    using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] rawResponse = webclient.UploadFile(httpUrl, xmlNewFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Remote Response: {0}", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    uploadError = true;
}
```

My httpUrl looks like `http://www.example.com:1234/upload`.

Problem is I'm getting a first chance exception ("A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll") immediately after running the line with the UploadFile command.
I can open the given URL on the given port with my browser, so the connection itself shouldn't be the problem.

Any ideas where to begin my search for the causing error?
Thanks!

EDIT: Ok, thanks to you guys now I know that I get an error from the server.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
 at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
 at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String fileName)
 at XML_Export.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 177
```

Funny thing is I get a "200 OK" with my browser... Hm.

Comment: What's the message from the `WebException`? And if you look at `http://www.example.com/upload` does the form post to another location?

Comment: Hint: catching an exception and not doing anything with it, not even logging it, is rarely a good idea.

Comment: The httpUrl in my browser gives me a white page with "HTTP/1.1 200 OK DATE: 19.09.2014 TIME: 16:32:58 CET".
Ok, I'll have to try how to log the exception - give me some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to examine the exception being trown. I usually log it in this way

```
    try
    {
        //some cool stuff with webClient
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var s = reader.ReadToEnd();

            throw new Exception(s, ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
```